# Creating a structure and calling functions for multiple user inputs, and passing this through the structure to display the information

Tags: c++, arrays, function, data-structures

I must create a C++ program that asks the user to input different products  information. So I created a structure to organize the members for the products, and I must use 3 functions, 1 to ask the user for their input, 1 to display the input, and 1 to display the last member Count for every Product item.

**My code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;


struct Product  //Structure
{
    char Name[25]; //Product Name
    char Type[25]; //Product Type
    char Exp_Date[25]; //Product Expiration Date
    double Price; //Product Price
    double Discount_Percentage; //Product Discount Percentage
    int Count; //Product Count in stock.
};

//Function Prototypes
Product Receive_Product_Information(Product);
void Display_All_Product_Information(Product & item);
void Display_Each_Product_Count(Product & item);

int main()
{
    Product Item[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the product information for the number " << i+1 << "item" << endl;

        Product item[2];
        Item[i] = Receive_Product_Information(item[2]);
    }

    cout << "marker" << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        Product item[2];
        Display_All_Product_Information(item[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        Product item[2];
        Display_Each_Product_Count(item[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

//Function Definitions

Product Receive_Product_Information(Product item)
{
    cout << "Enter Product Name: ";
    cin>>item.Name;

    cout << "Enter the Product Type: ";
    cin>>item.Type;

    cout << "Enter the Product Expiration Date: ";
    cin>>item.Exp_Date;

    cout << "Enter the Product Price: ";
    cin >> item.Price;

    cout << "Enter the Product Discount Price: ";
    cin >> item.Discount_Percentage;

    cout << "Enter the Product Count: ";
    cin >> item.Count;

    cout << endl << endl;

    return item;
}

void Display_All_Product_Information(Product &item)
{
    cout << "Name: " << item.Name<< endl;
    cout << "Type: " << item.Type << endl;
    cout << "Exp Date: " << item.Exp_Date << endl;
    cout << "Price: $" << item.Price << endl;
    cout << "Discount Percentage: " << item.Discount_Percentage << endl;
    cout << "Count: " << item.Count << endl;
    return ;
}

void Display_Each_Product_Count(Product &item)
{
    cout << "Product Count: " << item.Count << endl;
    return ;
}
```

**My Problem:**

My problem now is that the members Name, Type and Exp_Date are not being displayed as strings (i.e, Apple, Fruit, December) instead I get (##$%%#$%$%#)

Comment: By the way I am limiting the program to ask only for 2 products for simplicity, however the program must ask for 30 products. But to test I left it at 2.

Comment: Use `for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)` Instead.

Comment: Thanks, will apply the fix and see what happens.

Comment: Okay I have updated the code. It accurately displays the number of products now. However, the display function is having trouble showing the correct format for name, type, and exp date (I get gibberish). The user is inputting actual names, should I be using string instead of char for those variables?

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple issues with this code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
```

This `for` statement executes a loop, with `i` set to 1, and 2, on its two iterations, respectively. Let's keep this in mind, while the rest of the loop is examined.

```
    Product item[2];
```

This declares an array of two `Products`: item[0] and item[1]

```
Item[i] = Receive_Product_Information(item[i]);
```

The first bug here is on the second iteration, this will reference `item[2]`, since `i` will be 2, see above.

Unfortunately, only `item[0]` and `item[1]` exist, this is undefined behavior. `item` is a two-element array, and in two element array you have element #0 and element #1. Not element #1 and element #2.

This also applies to the `Item` array too. It's actually worse in `Item`'s case, since it's assigned to. The typical results on most implementations is a corrupted stack, and and a crash.

```
Product Receive_Product_Information(Product item)
```

The `Receive_Product_information`() function receives its argument by value. However, the argument was copied from an as-yet uninitialized locally-scoped object, in the caller's scope. Technically, this is not a 100% bug, but this is considered poor practice. Either the parameter should be passed by reference, or the object's contents should be properly initialized.

Additionally, it seems that passing the `Product` parameter does not really do anything usefl.`Receive_Product_Information`() appears to use standard input to initialize the contents of `item` ... and then immediately return it. So, why did it need it in the first place?

`Receive_Product_Information`() does not need this parameter at all. It simply needs to construct a new instance of `Product` by itself, and then return it.

There may or may not be other problems with this code, this is just what I immediately noticed, at first glance.

Comment: Thank you for your input Sam. I will take your edits in consideration when I get the code working exactly how I want it, and add better style to it. I am still 2 months new into C++ and so my style is not refined :D